# HTML <body> with background image

Tags: html, css, background-image, viewport

Lets say I have a  tag and in the CSS, I define it as having a bacground image of 1px wide, with repeat-x...Also for this body, I do not define or give any width..

There is some other content present on the page as well..

Now my question is what or how wide will this background image given to the body span...Like what will be it's bounding box and what will be it's width ?

Comment: You can check it yourself in easy way. And the time you'll spent is almost the same as the time to post this topic.

Comment: I completely agree, this question is unnecessary. Just open a web browser and text editor.

Comment: The question is not about editing and opening in browser, as anyone can do that...I wanted to understand the logic behind how the rendering happens...Hope u UNDERSTAND !!

Comment: @hmthr Nothing about "how it works?" in your initial topic. "Now my question is what or how wide..."

Comment: @silex There are some things which should be understood and not needed to be explicitly specified....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be bound to the element (and therein the size of the element) that has been specified in the CSS per the CSS rules of specificity. In the case of the `<BODY>` tag, it will continue for the width of the browser window.

If the element has inherited it's width from a parent element for some reason the background image will go for this parent elements specified width less padding and margins.

More info on the rules of specificity at [Smashing Magazine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the body tag is unconstrained by any CSS or scripting, then it's width will be the larger of the width of the window or the max width of the content within it (similar rules as a div).  So, your background will repeat full width.  An unconstrained body height will only be as tall as the content inside it.